# Java string method error

Tags: java, class

I prepared Date and DateTest classes which show below;

**Date Class**

```
public Date( String m, int d, int y)
{
this("m",d,y);
}
```

**DateTest Class**

```
Date myDate2 = new Date("april",18 , 2013);
System.out.println(myDate2);
```

But I receive below error message. Can anyone advise me what the problem is and how I can fix it.

**Error Message**
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    Recursive constructor invocation Date(String, int, int)

```
at Date.<init>(Date.java:24)
at DateTest.main(DateTest.java:10)
```

Answer (score 4):

Judging by the error message, I'd say that calling the `this()`, is what's causing the problem

```
public Date( String m, int d, int y)
{
this("m",d,y);
}
```

apparently calling `this("m",d,y);` in your constructor means that your'e making recursive calls in your constructor, which doesn't even make sense.

---

My guess is that maybe you're looking to do something along the lines of

```
public Date( String m, int d, int y)
{
    this.Month = m;
    this.Day = d;
    this.Year = y;
}
```

Comment: so, how can I fix it Sam ?

Comment: @Behzat get rid of that line.  If you elaborate on what you think that line is supposed to to, I might be able to tell you how to replace it

Answer (score 1):

Calling this inside the constructor is making it infinitely recursive. Hence that error. You would be better off creating a constructor with some setter methods. Read about constructor design pattern, that should help.